# expect script regex not working

Tags: regex, expect

This script is failing to work as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 2
set server [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set mac [lindex $argv 3]
set interface "po1"
spawn ssh $user@$server
expect "Password:"
send -- "$password\n"
expect "*>"
send "show mac address-table address $mac\n"
# 100      1cc1.de65.441c   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Port-channel43
expect -re { (\d+) *($mac) *(dynamic|static) *(.*) *(.*)} {
        set interface $expect_out(5,string)
        expect "*>"
        send "show interface $interface status\n"
}
send "exit\n"
interact
```

After issuing the show mac command above, the output contains one line that looks like the one commented below it. but the following expect -re block is never hit, making it time out and send the exit command.

Sample output:
    spawn ssh user@host
    Password:

```
================= Host login banner  =================
host>show mac address-table address 1cc1.de65.441c
Unicast Entries
 vlan     mac address     type        protocols               port
---------+---------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------------
 100      1cc1.de65.441c   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Port-channel43


host>exit
Connection to host closed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct and inside braces substitutions won't happen. i.e. `$mac` won't be substituted as it is inside braces.

```
expect {
    -re "\\d+\\s+$mac\\s+(dynamic|static)\\s+\\S+\\s+(\\S+)" { set interface $expect_out(2,string); # Add your further code}
}
```

Comment: If we need to extract only the port info, then other items we can simply match it with `\S`. Currently, I have assumed like you only need port info. Customise it if you want.