# How to match regular expression in expect programming

Tags: regex, expect

In expect programming how to check for the regular expression to match alphanumeric characters?

I am doing the following:

```
    expect {
        set prompt ([0-9]|[a-z])
        -re $prompt {
            puts "Hello world..."
        }            
    }
```

But it is showing the error : invalid command name "0-9"

Can anyone tell in expect programming how to match the regular expression?

Comment: Perhaps, `expect {
    -re "[a-zA-Z0-9]" {  # Add your further code}
}`? Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757109/expect-script-regex-not-working).

Comment: No that didn't work. Same error is coming.

Comment: `[` needs to be escaped with '\'.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `set prompt ...` command out of the `expect` command. Also, your regex is way too generic: lots of things besides a prompt can match a number or a letter. Best practice is to match the **end** of the prompt. If your prompt ends with a `$` and a space, use this:

```
set prompt {\$ $}
expect {
    -re $prompt {
        puts "Hello world..."
    }            
}
```

Comment: Hi Glen, Thanks for the reply. But my prompt doesn't end with $. It expect just alphanumeric characters. So what should be the case?